# 500 Server Error when serving from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application hosted on `GAE` that serves audio files from `Google Cloud Storage` using `CloudStorageTools::serve()`, however for the last 4 days it has been returning a `500 Error` when I try to serve files that reads:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

My `GAE` logs say the requests are returning 200, so it seems the problem is with `Google Cloud Storage` itself.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Does anyone have any insight as to what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Yes. It's still giving me the same 500 error.

Comment: This issue seems to affect your particular project. To further investigate, you should open a private issue in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901

Comment: Indeed. It seems to be just me. I can't find any mention of any problems anywhere else. Thanks for the link. I'll give that a go.